# Create an AST from bash in C

Tags: c, bash, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to build a mini Bash interpreter in C without the help of any fancy library (i.e from scratch). I have to manage simple operators like **'<', '|', '<<', '>>', '>'**.
I am told to build an AST of the input to facilitate the execution process. The thing is that I don't understand how I am supposed to build one.

So far I made a linked-list of my input turned into tokens but can't figure how to make an AST out of it:

```
typedef struct       s_token
{
    enum e_TokenType type;
    char             *lexeme;
    struct s_token   *prev;
    struct s_token   *next;
}                    t_token;
```

Could you explain me how to turn this into a functionnal AST ? For example with this input:

```
cat << EOF > file | wc -c | tr -d " " > file2
```

I imagine the AST would look like:

[image]
I have seen other posts describing how to but they were in JS/Python (I am not familiar with these languages) and using libraries for the part that interests me.

Comment: "without the help of any fancy library" -- do [lex & yacc](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/presentation/c134/1a6e6e7e60c590e8e2897a272e574df5b0d4.pdf) count as "fancy"? They've been around since the mid-1970's so...

Comment: @bishop Yeah, i should have said "from scratch" because i want to code the whole process myself.

Comment: See also http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10 and https://github.com/jalanb/jab/blob/master/src/bash/bash.bnf for possible inspiration.

Comment: @bishop - I tried that bash.bnf but it is very incomplete - no handling for ` or $ and presumably more

Comment: @bishop , got a new URL? I'd love to learn up on lex & yacc but that link is now 404

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would create an AST more like this:

```
                         __ PIPELINE__
                     ___/              \____
                    /                       \
            COMMAND                    __ PIPELINE _
          /        \                  /             \
    ARGUMENTS   REDIRECTIONS      COMMAND         _ COMMAND __
        |          |     |           |           /            \
       cat        <<     >       ARGUMENTS    ARGUMENTS   REDIRECTIONS
                   |     |         |   |      |   |   |        |
                 "..."  file      wc  -c      tr  -d " "       >
                                                               |
                                                             file2
```

Notable differences from yours:

- Commands are composed of a list of arguments and a list of redirections.
- Redirections have a type (`<`, `>`, `>>`, etc.) and a either a string or a file as source/target.
- The `EOF` heredoc is converted to a plain string node (`"..."` above). A here document is ultimately just syntactical sugar for a string. If I were doing it I'd handle `EOF` at the lexing stage and turn it into a simple string for the parser to handle. `EOF` wouldn't show up in the AST.

It's a rough sketch, but the idea is to represent the components in a more logical manner. The way you drew yours, `>` and `<<` look like binary operators with the other pieces as operands. That's how you'd parse a C program, but not a shell command.